# Convert a bitmap with white and black areas to a list of cartesian position using C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, converters

[image: Bitmap to be converted]

How can I convert a bitmap to a list of custom points `List<CustomPoints> myImage` using C#

```
Class CustomPoints
{
  double X {get;set;}
  double Y {get;set;}
  bool IsBlack {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: The slow way is GetPixel.  That faster way is LockBits.

Comment: Yes, I am loading the images and I am saving it as a bitmap object in my code  Bitmap temp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName); but after the have the object I don't know I can handle the image

Comment: @LarsTec thanks you should add your comment as answer to mark it and other people can use it. I tested using var pixel1 = temp.GetPixel(0, 0); and it works so now I just need to iterate over the images coordinates. Thanks I don't know how use LoackBits but I think that with getpixel I have a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the bitmap and check each value by using the GetPixel function:

[From Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx):

```
private void GetPixel_Example(PaintEventArgs e)
{
  // Create a Bitmap object from an image file.
  Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap("Grapes.jpg");

  // Get the color of a pixel within myBitmap.
  Color pixelColor = myBitmap.GetPixel(50, 50);

  // Fill a rectangle with pixelColor.
  SolidBrush pixelBrush = new SolidBrush(pixelColor);
  e.Graphics.FillRectangle(pixelBrush, 0, 0, 100, 100);
}
```

But using the GetPixel function is slow, especially when the images get larger.  In that case, your are advised to use [LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Use the LockBits method to lock an existing bitmap in system memory so that it can be changed programmatically. You can change the color of an image with the SetPixel method, although the LockBits method offers better performance for large-scale changes.